# How to set a Linux user's $HOME directory to /dev/null without warnings?

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a python script and put it into /bin. What I need is to let user could only run this script when they log in my computer by ssh.
I set an alias to generate user information as below:

```
alias USER_GEN='useradd -d /dev/null -s /bin/my_shell.py'
```

**Problems**:

- Every time when I use USER_GEN to create an user account, the bash warns me "The home directory is exists."
- After creating user account and log into my computer the bash warns me """
  No directory /dev/null!!
  Logging in with Home = "/" .
  """"

**Question**:

How to let those warning disappear?

Comment: Why it is unclear? I think that question is quite clear....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/dev/null` is not a directory. It is a (special) file. A home directory is expected to be a directory. If it is not, the `login` process will use the root directory as a home directory, as indicated.

If you want the user to not be able to create files in their home directory, don't give them write permissions on the directory. But make sure that it is a directory.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. In fact, I wish user will not get a $HOME directory. I can change the alias to "useradd -M -s/bin/my_shell.py". but when user login, they were warned of "no directory /home/$user" instead, I just want to have a solution to make this tip disappear... pls help me

Comment: @Bing: Every user must have a home directory, because there must always be a "current working directory", in order to run any program. So you need to create a directory to be the home directory for your users. There is no other solution. The system will always make *some* directory the home directory.